# Editing ng-repeat objects

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do you go about editing an array of objects bound to a table using ng-repeat ?

I have the following starting array.

```
var students = [{
  "FName": "Tom",
  "LName": "Wilcox"
}, {
  "FName": "Kevin",
  "LName": "Johnson"
}, {
  "FName": "Annebelle",
  "LName": "Smith"
}, {
  "FName": "Kelly",
  "LName": "Masters"
}, {
  "FName": "Phillip",
  "LName": "Smith"
}, ];
```

I then push two of the students onto a second array and add a new property called "Grade" like this:

```
var testTakers = [];
var s;
for (s = 0; s < students.length; s++) {
  if (students[s].LName == "Smith") {
    students[s].Grade = "";       // New Grade Property
    testTakers.push(students[s]);
  }
}
$scope.TestTakers = testTakers;
```

I add a new 'Grade' property to the two selected objects and bind to a table using ng-repeat. The Grade' property is bound to a textbox for editing.

```
<table class="table-striped">
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="student in TestTakers">
    <td class="col-md-2">{{student.FName}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">{{student.LName}}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" size="2em" ng-bind="Grade" style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I enter the grades into the textboxes Angular is not persisting those values.  My goal is to add grades to the two new student objects and then post them back up to the server.

A functioning [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pf10cPVvSrOzcFdz0dpz?p=preview) sample is here.  Thank you in advance for any assistance in helping me with this!

Comment: Is your aim to show all the students or just the Smiths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) instead of `ng-bind` inorder to set up a 2-way binding with the user input on the textbox and the bound view model.

```
<input type="text" size="2em" ng-model="student.Grade"  class="text-center" />
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mg8EHAvSeuPQALKBDsIt?p=preview)**

*Side Note: Since you already have boostrap css loaded you can just use existing css rule `text-center` instead of inline style to specify `style="text-align:center"`.*

Comment: thanks for looking into this.  Where you able to fork and update my plunker?  I added ng-model but still is not working.

Comment: And here is an example with updated shown on click of save. http://plnkr.co/edit/HrFnZduZoO75fcCBzf5u?p=preview